# Reset account on Mac Mini running OS X Lion

Tags: macos, password-recovery, apple-id

Mine is the sole administrative account of a 2010 Apple Mac Mini running OS X 10.7.  Somehow I have not been able to log in to the computer.

I've searched the net and heard that I could do a reset using my Apple ID and password. There is indeed an arrow in the password dialogue box with the description "reset using Apple ID".  But that arrow seems to be leading to nowhere.

Comment: Could you post a picture of what you're seeing on the screen so that we could help you with it further?

Comment: Need to do it later today as the machine is at home.  I am at the office right now.  Thanks for the comment though ...

Comment: You can boot into single-user mode and reset the password, provided you have the installation media. This may even be possible with the Lion Recovery partition, but I've not tested this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Everything is ok now as I have found my password.  It was related to the case of a certain alphabet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok now as I have stumbled back on the old password.  But I think I should explain what happened for those who are kind enough to look into my post and have tried to help.  And for those who may encounter a similar problem in the future.

1
About the reset by Apple ID.
I could not do it because I had not enabled the option by checking the check box in the first place.  The "You can reset with your apple ID" line in the dialogue box after my false attempts was quite misleading. But it did remind me to take notice of this very useful feature.

2
Be very careful when both upper and lower cases are used in a password.  In my case, 2 upper cases were used when only 1 was intended.  It happened when the typing was fast.  The worst part is it happened 2 times in a roll and when a password was being setup.

Just hope this answer can be helpful to someone; As we are increasingly burdened with more password setup...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the password in Lion, do the following:

- Reboot machine to the recovery partition.
- Select terminal from the Utilities menu.
- In terminal, type *resetpassword*, press enter and you will be presented with a window that allows you to reset the password of any user you wish from whichever volume has an installation of 10.7.
- Note that you will have to create a new keychain (user is presented with a menu at login) if you do not know the password of the account that you are resetting.

Cheers!